# Why didn't Shouko confess her feelings to Shoya afterwards?

Tags: koe-no-katachi

At the scene where Shouko tries to give a plant pot decoration thingy, she tried to confess her feeling to Shoya, but it was rather interpreted as '*tsuki* (moon)'.

I'm wondering now why Shouko didn't confess her feelings later?

Comment: to some people it takes a lot of courage to confess and when the other part misinterpret it, you can lose the courage to do that again.

Comment: She had been busy with ueno

Comment: Hmm, that indeed does make sense @Darjeeling

Answer (score 1):

After her initial failure, Shoko lost heart. Additionally, another opportunity never showed up.

First, let's examine what happened. Shoko finally felt comfortable enough around Shoya to try speaking aloud, and she changed her hair so that she could confess her feelings, but Shoya rejected her not once, but twice. The first time was by telling her to use sign language, even going so far to admit she sounded weird when Shoko asked. The second rejection came when he misunderstood her confession as meaning "moon". It really doesn't matter if Shoya genuinely was having a difficult time understanding what Shoko was saying; this outcome definitely hurt Shoko and shattered her confidence. This is evident when she runs home and throws herself on her bed, only communicates by sending two despairing texts to Yuzuru. She also went back to mainly using sign language to speak to Shoya. Supposing her romantic feelings even remained intact afterwards, she wouldn't be trying again for a long while. In her despair, she probably felt stupid for trying in the first place.

And then what happened? Soon afterwards, even more of their former classmates started showing up at the Tuesday meetings (invited or otherwise). Shoko was alone with Shoya a lot less often, so there were few opportunities to confess with him. And with what happened later in the story, Shoko became more preoccupied with her feelings of guilt, pushing any ideas of confessing far from mind.

Comment: Having been in that situation of misunderstanding: yes, exactly that, it took three friends to convince me to try again …

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not an expert in hand language but I did do some research on Google, website, etc. Poor Shoya... well, we can't blame him for it since he is still learning hand language (still in progress), unlike Shouko who is already a top-tier expert in hand language.

Go back to the almost ending bridge scene where Shouko & Shoya meet at midnight to confess everything. If I'm not wrong, after Shoya asked Shouko to help him to live and then he took Shouko's hand to do like "be my friend" (both hand palms held together), and then he do it again by holding her hand and shaking slowly. In that scene, there is a lot of mix up language for both of them, Shoya's point of view is "I want you to help me live and we support each other like best friends" but Shouko's point of view (OMG... did you ask me to let's get married?). Then Shoya starts to feel awkward and disgusted about what he is doing, there it seems Shouko gets the message of what is he trying to say and bursts out laughing and then to the "promise" hand language.

There you have it, it shows Shoya & Shouko did confess to each other by the end, but just not that straight up like what Shouko did in the confessing scene. But I'm sure their love relationship will start growing into maturity slowly in the future after the manga ends with Shoya holding Shouko's hand and walking into the door.